# How to place text on foreground of rectangle

Tags: itext

I have existing pdf document with white rectangle at top right coner. Hidden textfield is placed on rectangle. I have to put some text on the rectangle instead of hidden field. Here is my C# code:

```
public void setTextOverField(String sFieldName, String sText)
{
  IList<AcroFields.FieldPosition> positions = this._stamper.AcroFields.GetFieldPositions(sFieldName);
  Rectangle rect = positions[0].position;
  PdfContentByte cb = this._stamper.GetOverContent(positions[0].page);
  cb.BeginText();
  cb.SetFontAndSize(this._font, this._fontSize);
  cb.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_CENTER, sText, (rect.Left + rect.Right) / 2, (rect.Top + rect.Bottom) / 2, 0);
  cb.EndText();
}
```

Now the text is hidden under the white rectangle. If I make the rectangle transparent the text become visible.
How to bring text on foreground?

Comment: Your code sample looks correct. Maybe the error is caused by some other code elsewhere in your application.

Comment: ...or your white rectangle is part of some annotation, not the page content. Either way, please share a sample PDF illustrating the issue.